# Non-arrow navigation of auto-complete menu in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

When the auto-complete menu pops up in Emacs, what key do I use to navigate up and down the menu besides the up and down arrows? I tried `C-n` and `C-p` but that makes the menu disappear and move my cursor up and down the text area instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `M-p` and `M-n` to select the previous and next candidates respectively as described in the [Summary section](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md#summary) of the [User Manual](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md).

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question with the `C-n` and `C-p` keybindings could be:

```
; Cycle candidates with C-n and C-p
(setq ac-use-menu-map t)
```

Setting this variable (that comes from `auto-complete.el`) to `true` will remap the keybindings. `auto-complete.el` says *a special keymap `ac-menu-map` on completing menu will be used*. This is where the binding is made.